# Is income inequality decreasing?

Tags: inequality

Mr. Yaron Brooks from the Ayn Rand Institute argues that global income inequality is decreasing. True/false?

Comment: I don't see how that can possibly be substantiated by evidence

Comment: I vote to close because the answer does not provide essential information, like a summary of the arguments (like on what data was the claim based), links, or other relevant sources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not provide essential information

Comment: To be fair, I couldn't either find Yaron's arguments in writing, just youtube discussions.

Comment: @serakfalcon Don't trust any statistics you didn't manipulate yourself. I'm pretty sure that while inequality within countries is increasing in most countries, inequality between countries (say, over means of income for each country) is decreasing, simply by convergence in growth.

Comment: where? Over what time intervals?

Comment: I do not understand why this has been put on hold. The question and answer both have positive rep and there are well-defined measures of global income inequality that can be used to answer the question.

Comment: Thomas Piketty and his co-authors have spent a lot of time collecting data to address this question. See this webpage: http://topincomes.g-mond.parisschoolofeconomics.eu/. This work has certainly made it seem more feasible to find an answer to the question posed here than to many other questions posed in this forum.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fairly instructive figure showing a cross-country measure of income inequality:

[image: World Gini coefficient]

It shows that inequality was increasing for most of the last 35 years, but has started to decrease again recently. (You can read more at the source for this figure: http://www.conferenceboard.ca/hcp/hot-topics/worldinequality.aspx)

Once data is weighted by population, we see a longer-term trend for decreasing inequality (due to rapid growth in China and India, which contain around a third of the world's people:

[image]

As @FooBar notes in a comment, a pattern of decreasing income inequality is consistent with economic [theories of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_(economics)).

Comment: Perfect answer for the question, exactly what I was gonna do later the day if I had the time. Shows that the question (despite being short) is a good one and deserves staying open.

Comment: I agree. While it may not be possible to answer the question with true/false only, I believe it is possible to answer it in the differentiated way as for example in this answer.